# How can I adjust this positioning to follow a "zoom-to-point" effect?

Tags: lua, roblox

This is my 3rd day of googling and tinkering with my code, and I'm hopeless, I honestly need help, so please bear with me here.

**Explanation**

I'll start with explaining the basic concept. There is a 'character' in the middle of the screen, always perfectly centered. Under that layer is a big square, which I will refer to as the **canvas**. As you move around, the game is actually just simulating the movement, a 'virtual camera' if you will, so the character doesn't actually move, the canvas just moves behind it.

**My Problem**

In this game, the camera needs to be able to 'zoom' in and out, so to do this, I adjust the size of the canvas and everything else depending on the zoom value. (1 is default) The width and height of the canvas is always 8000 * the zoom value. This is fine, however, I am having major difficulty positioning the canvas so that it remains in the same relative position as you scale in and out - or rather a 'zoom to point' or 'zoom from point' effect. I simply cannot create the math for this.

**The Code**

```
    local oldScale = g.scale;
    local newScale = n.scaleTest.Value;
    g.scale = newScale;
    g.x = g.x + (g.x * newScale);
    g.y = g.y + (g.y * newScale);
```

g.scale represents the zoom value, everything will be adjusted to this size.

g.x and g.y are the coordinates of the canvas. The math in the code is completely incorrect.

n.scaleTest.Value is my temporary variable for the newly set scale. It can change at any time.

**Thoughts / Other Important Information**

I can retrieve the AbsolutePosition and AbsoluteSize of the canvas as well. I have considered implementing the distance from the canvas's edges to the character into my calculations, but I am not completely sure how to do this.

Thank you for any help, I would sincerely appreciate it, I am very stuck and don't know who to ask.

Comment: the math is different depending the order of  transformations (scale, translation, etc.) as well as what type of coordinate system you are using. We need to know what the api of your canvas and camera and the drawing code.